# Deleting Indexes from an ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist

I am trying to create a button that already has an index captures and just needs to delete from an `ArrayList<String>` and `ArrayList<Integer>`. The integer list deletes the index just fine but the string array do not. Code Below:

```
Globals:
ArrayList<String> QandItem = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer> Prices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayAdapter<String> left;
ArrayAdapter<Integer> right;
```

These are setup and filled in the on create method. I know they work correctly because I get output when viewing them on the device.

```
RemoveItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO
        if(i >= 0){
            QandItem.remove(i);
            Prices.remove(i);
            left.notifyDataSetChanged();
            right.notifyDataSetChanged();
            ItemList.setAdapter(left);
            PriceList.setAdapter(right);
        }
    }
});
```

Where `i` is the index I am trying to delete.

Comment: Is `i` an `Integer` or an `int`?

Comment: Then you have your answer. You're removing the element i, rather than removing the element which is at index i.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since i is an `Integer`, you are trying to remove the object `i` and not the element at position i. Try using `i.intValue()` instead.
See the difference between [ArrayList.remove(int index)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28int%29) and [ArrayList.remove(Object o)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29).

Answer (score 1):

If i is an `Integer` rather than a primitive `int`, as Keppil asked, `QandItem.remove(i)` will be trying to remove an object that it doesn't hold. Try this:

```
QandItem.remove(i.intValue())
```